# Qt connect between two classes not working

Tags: c++, qt, class

I have two classes: HoodPlanner and DrawRoad. Both classes inherit from QWidget and the the UI so I can access all UI elements in both classes.

Here's a snipped of both classes:

HoodPlanner:

```
#ifndef HOODPLANNER_H
#define HOODPLANNER_H

#include <ui_hoodplanner.h>
#include "drawroad.h"
#include <QtWidgets>

class HoodPlanner : public QWidget, private Ui::HoodPlanner
{
  Q_OBJECT
  private:
    // (...)

  public:
    explicit HoodPlanner(QWidget * = 0);
    // (...)

  private slots:
    // (...)
};

#endif // HOODPLANNER_H
```

DrawRoad:

```
#ifndef DRAWROAD_H
#define DRAWROAD_H

#include <ui_hoodplanner.h>
#include <QtWidgets>

class DrawRoad : public QWidget, private Ui::HoodPlanner
{
  Q_OBJECT
  private:
    // (...)

  public:
    explicit DrawRoad(QWidget *parent = 0);

  public slots:
    void drawSC4Street();
};

#endif // DRAWROAD_H
```

In HoodPlanner I have a connect that will be emitted whenever the itemSelection changes in table_ts2. I have the slot stored in DrawRoad, but inserting a reference to the DrawRoad object in third position brings up errors.

```
HoodPlanner::HoodPlanner(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
  setupUi(this);
  // (...)
  DrawRoad *drawRoad = new DrawRoad;
  connect(table_ts2, SIGNAL(itemSelectionChanged()), &drawRoad, SLOT(drawSC4Street()));
}
```

Snipped from DrawRoad.cpp:

```
#include "drawroad.h"

DrawRoad::DrawRoad(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
}

void DrawRoad::drawSC4Street()
{
  if(!table_ts2->selectionModel()->hasSelection()) return;
  // (...)
}
```

And the following errors occur whenever I run the app:

```
hoodplanner.cpp:12: Fehler: no matching function for call to 'HoodPlanner::connect(QTableWidget*&, const char [24], DrawRoad**, const char [17])'
mingw492_32\include\QtCore\qobject.h:213: Fehler: no type named 'Object' in 'struct QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<const char*>'
```

(and lots of notes)

The errors don't help me at all and I've searched in several topics for a solution, but none of them had my problem.

Comment: Have you forgot to `#include "drawroad.h"` into `HoodPlanner.cpp` ?

Comment: error says everything you need, "DrawRoad**". in your code you are taking point er of pointer  " &drawRoad, SLOT(drawSC4Street()));". remove ampersand and the error will disapear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
HoodPlanner::HoodPlanner(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
  setupUi(this);
  // (...)
  DrawRoad *drawRoad = new DrawRoad;
  connect(table_ts2, SIGNAL(itemSelectionChanged()), drawRoad, SLOT(drawSC4Street()));
}
```

You declrared drawRoad as a pointer:

```
DrawRoad *drawRoad = new DrawRoad;
```

And then you pass its address to connect() with &drawRoad.
In this case you are passing a pointer to a pointer address. Try without the `&`